# Eclipse: what is the difference between android-support-v7-appcompat and appcompat_v7?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

First off I'm soooooo frustrated trying to get android.appcompat....gridlayout to work. I've followed lots of tutorials and just keep getting that horrible "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout failed to instantiate" message. So I'm doing some serious detective work to try and understand everything about the compat libraries.

So like the title asks, what is the difference? I'm building the libs/android-...jar files, adding them to the path, following all the directions on https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Any insight? Should I just uninstall eclipse and start from scratch to try and do this? I'm working with a test project and nothing is working. I keep getting 1 instantiation errors along with an error saying "a resource already exists on disk 'C:......\android-supp..-gridlayout.settings' and '....prefs'.

Please please any insight. Have spent a long time on this. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they both refer to the same ["v7 appcompat library" discussed at the android developer](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) site.

You cannot just copy the jar file, as this library has resources that are referred to by your project so it needs to be added as a [library project with resources as discussed here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res).